# Spring Data JPA project as dependency of Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices, dependency-management

I would like to have a microservice project using Spring Boot that gets access to Entities and DAOs through a dependency that is created through Spring Data JPA project. The idea is that multiple microservices could get that dependency.

However, when the jar is assembled in the Spring Boot Data JPA project, a lot of dependencies are included in it through starter dependencies. Most them are also present in the Spring Boot Microservice project that uses it.

How would you go about building a jar through Spring Data JPA with just Entities and Repositories? I have not found any clear examples on how to achieve this, not sure If I am off with my thinking or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a jar just with entities and Spring Data JPA Repositories, why do you have Spring Boot in there in the first place? Just remove it and build a jar out of it with your favorite build tool.

Comment: Isnt spring necessary as part of a spring data jpa project? Can you point me to a spring data jpa project that is not spring boot?

Comment: Spring Framework is a dependency of Spring Data. Spring Boot isn't. You can use Spring Data without Spring Boot. For years there wasn't even a Spring Boot. You can look at integration tests for Spring Data JPA itself for example.

Answer (score 0):

To my view point, sharing domain entities between microservices is fundamentally wrong in microservices architecture.

Please learn about Domain Driven Design modelling. There are lots of articles and videos available on the internet.

[Domain Driven Design](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/domain-driven-design-services-architecture)

[Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)

Sharing means no duplication but more coupling.
Duplication leads to less coupling.

Comment: I am exposing a third party data source. Many of my microservices will need that data source to do reads but the microservice itself will be responsible for their own business processes which mean to insert or update into a few of those tables

Comment: Still not convincing , we can't design Microservices where one would read & other would write. It disobeys system of truth. If any other service wants to get the data then it needs to inter service communication, think about event driven architecture or get data through layer 7.